# flutter installing the .apk release app get stuck blank screen

Tags: android, flutter, dart, flutter-build, flutter-release

when I run my project in debug and even release mode using `flutter run --release` everything is fine but when I get the output apk files using `flutter build apk --split-per-abi` and installing it successfully it only launches a blank grayish screen, not showing my splash screen and my homepage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In flutter when you have a grey screen means that it has thrown an exception. Try revising the code to see if there is anything that can thow exception.

Comment: you mean put a try/catch block in main?